# Pivot table in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am very very new to `pyspark`. My data frame looks like -

```
id        value      subject
1          75         eng
1          80         his
2          83         math
2          73         science
3          88         eng
```

I want my data frame -

```
id     eng      his     math     science
1      .49      .51      0         0
2       0        0      .53       .47
3       1        0       0         0
```

That means row-wise summation and then divide with each cell. Want to calculate % of each cell.

I have done the following code but it's not working -

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

df = df.withColumn('rank',F.dense_rank().over(Window.orderBy("id","value","subject")))
df.withColumn('combcol',F.concat(F.lit('col_'),df['rank'])).groupby('id').pivot('combcol').agg(F.first('value')).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the following code works for you.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [ (1,75,'eng'), (1,80,'his'), (2,83,'math'), (2,73,'science'), (3,88,'eng') ]
  , [ 'id','value','subject' ]
)

# create the pivot table
df1 = df.groupby('id').pivot('subject').agg(F.first('value')).fillna(0)

# column names used to sum up for total
cols = df1.columns[1:]

# calculate the total and then percentage accordingly for each cols
df1.withColumn('total', sum([F.col(c) for c in cols])) \
   .select('id', *[ F.format_number(F.col(c)/F.col('total'),2).alias(c) for c in cols] ) \
   .show()
#+---+----+----+----+-------+                                                    
#| id| eng| his|math|science|
#+---+----+----+----+-------+
#|  1|0.48|0.52|0.00|   0.00|
#|  3|1.00|0.00|0.00|   0.00|
#|  2|0.00|0.00|0.53|   0.47|
#+---+----+----+----+-------+
```

Comment: you forget to put output for `total` column